# Parsing iptables log to insert into mysql

Tags: bash, awk, grep, iptables

My router sends its 'DROP' packets to my server via syslog to be logged to a file in the following manner:

> Oct 30 13:01:02 192.168.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=vlan2 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   SRC=93.108.197.92 DST=192.168.2.10 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51
>   ID=44828 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55552 DPT=33248 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN
>   URGP=0 OPT (020405840402080A0035BAC40000000001030300)
>
> Oct 30 13:01:06
>   192.168.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=vlan2 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   SRC=93.108.197.92 DST=192.168.2.10 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51
>   ID=44829 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55552 DPT=33248 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN
>   URGP=0 OPT (020405840402080A0035BEAE0000000001030300)
>
> Oct 30 13:01:07
>   192.168.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=vlan2 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   SRC=189.175.171.76 DST=192.168.2.10 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53
>   ID=260 PROTO=TCP SPT=14779 DPT=23 WINDOW=50523 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT
>   (020405AC)
>
> Oct 30 13:01:09 192.168.1.1 kernel:
>   DROP IN=vlan2 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   SRC=125.211.218.39 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=88 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48
>   ID=39896 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=29389 SEQ=1
>
> Oct 30 13:01:14 192.168.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=vlan2 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   SRC=93.108.197.92 DST=192.168.2.10 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51
>   ID=44830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55552 DPT=33248 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN
>   URGP=0 OPT (020405840402080A0035C6800000000001030300)

I'd like to put each field into a mysql db so I view and analyze later. I'm trying to think of the best way to parse/filter/do this. I'd like to do it in bash but I'm open to other alternatives/langs if it makes it way more efficient or easier.

My iptables log files are rotated every so often and I was going to create a bash/sed/awk script to look through each line of the log(s) and create an sql file so I can use a 'LOAD DATA INFILE' command to load all data into one INSERT statement.

As you can see above, an ICMP and TCP type of packet will differ from the way it is written to the file (number of fields after ID)

I have a few different ways to complete this:

1. Search by PROTO and the remaining awk 'print' commands are used to grab all relevant information.
2. Search for all [PARAM]=[VALUE] in every line, regardless of PROTO and just shove them in mysql and analyze later.

So far I have (I know this is basic, but I'm wondering if I should approach it differently before investing more time into it):

```
cat "$fw_file" | while read line; do
   type=$(grep -oP 'PROTO=\w+\s' | cut -d= -f2)
   df=$(grep -oP 'ID=\w+\sDF\s' | cut -d' ' -f2)
   # continuing on for all fields....
   # ......
done
```

If there a better, more efficient, way for me to do this instead of just grabbing all fields?

Comment: This is not really answering my question. You say I should use awk and read a book on awk. Do you think awk is the best, most efficient method to do this filtering of data? Do you think I should use python instead of bash or a shell in general?

Comment: That's correct, an answer to a question is posted as an answer. Other information such as I provided is posted as a comment. idk what you want to do yet since you haven't done what I suggested in my comment last week (`Fix your input format using the editors {} button and add the expected output given that input.`) so of course I don't know the best way to do it but in general awk is by far your best choice for general purpose text manipulation in UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

Before your begin working on your script (Reinventing the Wheel), For parsing logs and analyzing log data there are `opensource` tools that do the job efficently. Please consider them!

For your exact usecase, You Better use `Elasticsearch`,`Logstash`, `Kibana` (`ELK Stack`).
Some Advantages of `ELK Stack` comparing to script and relational database approach:

- Easier to store logs from multiple sources ( one can be your router)
- Scalable ( you probably get slowed pretty soon depending on your logs input rate)
- Very easy to visualize data in web interface with various charts using `kibana`.
- `Elasticsearch` has `REST API`, So your developers can do their own thing too!

There are many tutorials online to get you going pretty fast.

Comment: I appreciate your answer for already made tools - I'm all about that. These packages want java to be installed as these are written in java. I find java to be very bloated, do you have experience with any other firewall analyzing tools than the ELK package?

Comment: The best opensource tool for log shipping, storage, search and visualization is ELK, Although there are some commercial rivals like splunk. Java is pretty tunable in case of resource usage and depends on how much log size from how many sources you gonna store and analyze. You can get up and running with elk stack using official docker images in no time. Just try it  out, You will be amazed by power of it.